# Resume Robot running with updated case version

Tags: robotframework

I have a question about Robot Framework:

For example, I have 2 cases in a suite and I trigger the suite running for the 2 cases. After case 1 running finishes, I pause the running. Then I make some modification for case 2 and resume the running. However the Robot still run case 2 with the old version.

Is there any way to have Robot run case 2 with the updated version when resuming? I'm asking the question because it's important for my automation case writing/debugging. In some situation the automation suite setup requires about 20 minutes and I really hope to stay in the suite environment to write new case and make update based on the previous running result.

Comment: How do you pause? Also when you start a suite, robot parses the .robot files and everything else, when you pause and resume there won't be a second parsing, the first parsed context will be used. You could read through the robot API to see if you can somehow reparse the sources and modify the context.

Comment: Thanks for your info about the Robot parse mechanism. I plan to pause the running either by manually clicking the "Pause" button or setting the flag "Pause on failure" to pause the failed case.